# no such table: audio_genres_map Error in Android R / 11

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, mediastore

I am trying following code in `Android R / 11`

```
String[] columns = {
                        MediaStore.Audio.Genres._ID,
                        MediaStore.Audio.Genres.NAME,
                };
                try {
                    query = MediaStore.Audio.Genres._ID + " IN" +
                            " (SELECT " + MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.GENRE_ID +
                            " FROM audio_genres_map WHERE " + MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.AUDIO_ID + " IN" +
                            " (select _id from audio_meta where is_music != 0))";
                    cursor = Common.getInstance().getContentResolver()
                            .query(MediaStore.Audio.Genres.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                    columns, query, null, MediaStore.Audio.Genres.NAME);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    query = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.GENRE_ID + " IN" +
                            " (SELECT " + MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.GENRE_ID + " FROM audio_genres_map WHERE " +
                            MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.AUDIO_ID + " IN" +
                            "(select _id from audio_meta where is_music != 0))";
                    cursor = Common.getInstance().getContentResolver()
                            .query(MediaStore.Audio.Genres.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                    columns, query, null, MediaStore.Audio.Genres.NAME);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
                mApp.getDBAccessHelper().getWritableDatabase().delete(DataBaseHelper.GENRES_TABLE,
                        null, null);
                ////Log.v(TAG, "genre size " + cursor.getCount());
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        ContentValues genre = new ContentValues();
                        genre.put(DataBaseHelper.GENRE_ID, cursor.getString(0));
                        genre.put(DataBaseHelper.GENRE_NAME, cursor.getString(1));
                        ArrayList<Album> albums = getAlbumsForSelection(
                                "GENRES", cursor.getString(0));
                        if (albums != null && albums.size() > 0) {
                            genre.put(DataBaseHelper.GENRE_ALBUM_ART, otherUtils.getAlbumArtUri(albums.get(0)._Id).toString());
                            genre.put(DataBaseHelper.NO_OF_ALBUMS_IN_GENRE, "" + albums.size());
                        }
                        mApp.getDBAccessHelper().getWritableDatabase().insert(DataBaseHelper.GENRES_TABLE, null, genre);
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
```

this code was `working on Andorid Q and earlier`, however it did not work in android R

this is the error as per crashalytics

```
no such table: audio_genres_map (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT _id, name FROM audio_genres WHERE (genre_id IN (SELECT genre_id FROM audio_genres_map WHERE audio_id IN(select _id from audio_meta where is_music != 0))) ORDER BY name
keyboard_arrow_up
android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel (DatabaseUtils.java:184)
arrow_drop_down
android.content.ContentResolver.query (ContentResolver.java:918)
```

as per

https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_packages_providers_mediaprovider/blob/master/src/com/android/providers/media/MediaProvider.java

there should be a `audio_genres_map` table, there were lot of changes in `android R` but there is no proper Documentiation has the`MediaStore` been changed as well where can we find the documentation

Comment: Thats how ends using not public API ... table is in different database which you have no access

Comment: I've removed the [tag:r] tag, please correct me if somehow this is connected to the R programming language.

Comment: @selvin then whats the solution  ignoring empty genres

Comment: @1234567 Did you find any solution for this?